# Django + Celery task never done

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to run the example app Django+Celery from official celery repository:
https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django
I cloned the repo, ran RabbitMQ in my docker container:

```
docker run -d --hostname localhost -p 15672:15672 --name rabbit-test rabbitmq:3
```

ran celery worker like this:

```
celery -A proj worker -l INFO
```

When I try to execute a task:

```
python ./manage.py shell
>>> from demoapp.tasks import add, mul, xsum
>>> res = add.delay(2,3)
>>> res.ready()
False
```

I always get `res.ready()` is `False`. The output from worker notify that task is recieved:

```
[2022-12-14 14:43:20,283: INFO/MainProcess] Task demoapp.tasks.add[29743cee-744b-4fa6-ba68-36d17e4ac806] received
```

but it's never done.
What might be wrong? How to catch the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run worker using `--pool` option. Like this:

```
celery -A proj worker -l INFO --pool solo
```